# Может ли базовый класс знать что-то про методы потомков?

Tags: python, наследование, методы

Разбираюсь сейчас с наследованием в Python, а также с магическими методами. Имеется код:

```
class Researcher:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return 'Nothing found :()\n'

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print('Looking for {}'.format(name))
        return super().__getattribute__(name)


obj = Researcher()

print(obj.attr)
print(obj.method)
print(obj.DFG2H3J00KLL)
```

Возник вопрос: откуда объект object() (который создался после вызова `super()`) знает о методе `__getattr__` класса `Researcher`? Разве базовый класс знает что-то про методы потомков?

Comment: Я немного запутался - какой объект `object()`? И непонятно, о каком базовом классе речь? (`obj.method`, `obj.DFG2H3J00KLL` - тоже), может, часть кода пропала?

Comment: Говоря об объекте `object()`, я имею ввиду объект базового класса `object` (для потомка `Researcher`), который создаётся при вызове `super()`. `obj.method`, `obj.DFG2H3J00KLL` - умышленное обращение к несуществующим атрибутам. С целью посмотреть на вызов метода `__getattribute__` класса `Researcher`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`super()` вовсе не возвращает просто объект родительского класса.

В этом легко убедиться, если перед строчкой где вы его вызываете поставить `print(super())`. Если такое проделать, то код в этом месте выведет:

`<super: <class 'Researcher'>, <Researcher object>>`

Как видите, это не экземпляр родительского класса `object`. Это особый объект-обёртка, который управляет вызовом методов из классов выше по иерархии для текущего объекта. И вот эта обёртка и знает всё и про методы Researcher, и про всех его родителей.

UPD: Действительно, как правильно отметил автор вопроса в комментариях, если заменить super() на object(), то код всё равно работает. Но это уже не связано с наследованием, а связано с нюансами работы `__getattr__` и `__getattribute__`

Дело в том, что `__getattribute__`, если он реализован, то он срабатывает для вообще всех обращений к атрибутам - как к существующим, так и к несуществующим. В то время, как `__getattr__` срабатывает только для обращения к несуществующим атрибутам - то есть тогда, когда при обращении к атрибуту произошло исключение `AttributeError`.

То есть вот что происходит, когда вы меняете super на object:

1. Код делает обращение к атрибуту объекта.
2. Так как это объект класса Researcher, для которого есть метод `__getattribute__`, то код выполняет именно этот метод.
3. Внутри него идёт обращение к `object().__getattribute__(name)`
4. Для экземпляра класса object обращение к аттрибуту работает стандартно, то есть для неизвестного аттрибута, такого как `DFG2H3J00KLL` будет выброшено исключение `AttributeError`
5. Т.к. при возникновении этого исключение всегда проверяется, есть ли у объекта `__getattr__`, и так как всё это происходит всё ещё для экземпляра `Researcher`, а у него этот метод есть, то именно он и срабатывает.

Проиллюстрировать это можно следующими примерами.

Демонстрация того, что исключение AttributeError действительно выбрасывается:

```
class Researcher:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return 'Nothing found :()\n'

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print('Looking for {}'.format(name))
        try:
            object().__getattribute__(name)
        except Exception as e:
            print('!!! ', type(e))


obj = Researcher()

print(obj.attr)
print(obj.method)
print(obj.DFG2H3J00KLL)
```

Демонстрация того, что даже если мы не будем обращаться ни к object, ни к super, а просто руками выбросим AttributeError, то всё будет работать так же, как и изначально:

```
class Researcher:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return 'Nothing found :()\n'

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print('Looking for {}'.format(name))
        raise AttributeError


obj = Researcher()

print(obj.attr)
print(obj.method)
print(obj.DFG2H3J00KLL)
```

Comment: Понял, картина стала яснее. Но почему если запустить тот же код, но вместо `super().__getattribute__(name)` написать `object().__getattribute__(name)` программа будет работать также?

Comment: @Chudvan, посмотрел. Да, действительно, тут так совпало, что на нюансы super накладывается ещё один нюанс работы `__getattr__` и `__getattribute__`. Сейчас допишу в мой ответ подробно.

Comment: @Chudvan Я сейчас протестировал. Если использовать `object()`, то всё ломается. Просто совпадение, что в Вашем примере продолжает работать. Это нюансы вызова методов.

Comment: @Chudvan, я дополнил ответ

Comment: Огромное спасибо, за подробное объяснение!